# How can I trigger an action when the date changes in the input field of a date picker in Sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

currently, I am trying to load data based on the date that I select from a date picker. However, I am encountering issues and cannot seem to make it work. Additionally, the console log is not displaying the date too. Can someone please assist me in resolving this issue?

+page.svelte

```html
<form method="get" action="?/getDate" on:submit|preventDefault bind:this={form}>
  <input
    on:change={form.requestSubmit()}
    name="inputDate"
    id="inputDate"
    type="date"
    class="p-4 rounded-2xl"
  />
</form>
```

+page.server.ts

```js
export const actions = {
  getDate: async ({ request }) => {
    const date = await request.formData();
    console.log(date.get('inputDate'));

    const data = await getData(date.get('inputDate') as string);
    
    return data;
  },
} satisfies Actions;
```

Comment: Try `on:change={form.requestSubmit}` or `on:change={() => form.requestSubmit()}`

Comment: Still can't get `console.log` working.

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this in the wrong way imo.
Usually you would load the data in the `load` function, you can use the searchParams to pass the input date to it: so in your `+page.server.js` you would have this:

```js
export const load = async ({ url ) => {
  const inputDate = url.searchParams.get('inputDate') ?? '';
  const items = getData(inputDate);
  return {
    items,
    inputDate
  };
}
```

Now the issue becomes how to update the searchParams effectively.
In your `+page.svelte` set:

```html
<script>
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
  export let data
</script>
<form>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="inputDate"
    on:input={(ev) => {
      const inputDate = ev.currentTarget.value;
      goto(inputDate.length ? `./?inputDate=${inputDate}` : `./`, { keepFocus: true });
    }}
    value={data.inputDate}
  />
  <noscript><button>submit</button></noscript>
</form>

<div>
 // do stuff with data.items here
</div>
```

Here we use `on:input` to construct and navigate to a new url with changed searchParams, this will trigger the `load` function, updating your items.

For users without javascript, updating at every keystroke would be jarring (they would also lose focus btw) so when js is disabled we show a submit button.  Submitting the form like this, will do a standard GET, adding all the inputfields as searchParams, so we get the same effect as navigating and the new items will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is in the form's method.  GET submissions don't carry a body.  All data goes into the query string.  Your data is not in `request.formData()`.  Change the method to POST or read the query string.